# VBO won't display (sdl with glew)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew, vbo

I'm just starting out using VBOs (using SDL/glew). I'm trying to start out using the simple example of a cube - actually at the moment just the one face of a cube - but I can't get anything to display

my vertex structure is defined as follows:

```
struct Vertex
{
float x, y, z;          //Vertex coords
float tx, ty;           //Texture coords
float nx, ny, nz;       //Normal coords
};
```

The cube is then generated like so:

```
        Vertex temp;

        //NOTE: Perspective is from looking at the cube from the outside
   //Just trying to display one face for the moment to simplify
        //Back face ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        temp.x = 0.f; temp.y = 0.f; temp.z = 0.f;       //Bottom Right  - 0
        temp.nx = 0.f; temp.ny = 0.f; temp.nz = 1.f; // This stays the same for the rest of the face
        temp.tx = 1.f; temp.ty = 0.f;
        m_vertices.push_back(temp);

        temp.x = 0.f; temp.y = m_fHeight; temp.z = 0.f;         //Top Right - 1
        temp.tx = 1.f; temp.ty = 1.f;
        m_vertices.push_back(temp);

        temp.x = m_fWidth; temp.y = m_fHeight; temp.z = 0.f;    //Top Left      - 2
        temp.tx = 0.f; temp.ty = 1.f;
        m_vertices.push_back(temp);

        temp.x = m_fWidth; temp.y = 0.f; temp.z = 0.f;  //Bottom Left - 3
        temp.tx = 0.f; temp.ty = 0.f;
        m_vertices.push_back(temp);

        m_indeces.push_back(0); m_indeces.push_back(1); m_indeces.push_back(2);
        m_indeces.push_back(2); m_indeces.push_back(3); m_indeces.push_back(0);


        //Generate the vertex buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBufferID);
        //Bind the vertex buffer                                                                                                
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferID);
        //Fill the vertex buffer - size is 24*sizeof(Vertex) bcs 6 faces with 4 corners
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 4, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertex) * 4, &m_vertices); // Actually upload the data

        //Set up the pointers
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(20));
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));


        //Generate the index buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &m_indexBufferID);                                      
        //Bind the index buffer                                                                                         
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indexBufferID);
        //Fill the index buffer- size is 36*sizeof(uint) bcs 6 traingle coords in 1 face * 6 faces
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte) * 6, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLubyte) * 6, &m_indeces); // Actually upload the data
```

which is then sent to render in a seperate function:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

// Resetup the pointers. 
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(20));
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

//Draw the indexed elements
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

and BUFFER_OFFSET() is a simaple macro defined as:

```
// A helper macro to get a position
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
```

But I just can't get anything to display - applying the same texture etc. to a cube in immediate mode shows up fine.

The weird thing is that occasionaly something very strange will get displayed, which is different every time - so maybe it's some sort of initialization error?

Comment: Plural of "index" is "indexes" or "indices".

Comment: What does glGetError() tell you?

Comment: Is `glDrawElements` without VBOs working for you?

Comment: BTW, `offsetof` (which is a standard-provided macro) would be much better than your `BUFFER_OFFSET`.

Comment: glGetError() seems to be returning GL_NO_ERROR

Comment: yeah - draw elements seems to work ok without VBOs.  Thanks, I'll check out the offsetof macro.  Also apologies, no spell good in code more.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `&m_vertices` and `&m_indeces` to `m_vertices` and `m_indeces` in the call to `glBufferSubData()` worked!

Answer (score 0):

None of your sizes match the comments, I suspect you're reading off the end of the VBO.

Comment: Hi, sorry I obviously forgot to ammend the comments - I think sizes are correct because I'm currently only trying to render one face, which should be described by 4 Vertex structs (in the comments it says 24 because for a full cube x6 faces) the same thing goes for the number of indeces